# VSCode select next occurrence of variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In VSCode on Mac, I can use the keyboard shortcut `Cmd + D` to select the next occurrence of my currently highlighted text.

For example, if I highlight the variable `order` on line 1 in the below code, hitting `Cmd + D` causes `order_form` on line 2 to be partially highlighted, and hitting `Cmd + D` again causes `order` to be highlighted on line 3.

```
1. order = "Some string"
2. order_form = create_form()
3. return "Here is your order: " + order
```

However, I just want to select the actual variable `order` on lines 1 and 3 (i.e. excluding the text that is part of the variable `order_form`)

What keyboard shortcut can I use to just highlight the actual variables named `order` on lines 1 and 3?

Comment: if you select text with `Shift_Arrow` and then `Ctrl+D` it will find all occurences of the text. If you place the cursor in the word `order` (no chars selected) and press `Ctrl+D` it will select the current word and a next `Ctrl+D` will only select word instances

Comment: A little more clarification: do you want to select all occurrences of the symbol in the file or just the next occurrence?  And do you want to progressively add the next selection to all the previous selections - i.e., save the selections as you go.  I could write an extension that does the select all or just select the next pretty easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> functionality uses the current Find widget settings "behind the scenes" - whether that Find widget is visible or not.

So you would get the behaviour you want if the `Whole Word` option was enabled in that Find widget first before you began <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>'ing.

Alternatively, as the demo below shows when you place your cursor on the word you want `order` you can then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> which will toggle the `Whole Word` option on and off.  Note the little box that opens in the top right of the editor that shows only the Find options.

Then all your find next occurrences with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will find only what you want with that `Whole Word` option still enabled.

If you want to skip any of those occurrences, you can use the command

```
Add Selection To Previous Find Match
editor.action.addSelectionToPreviousFindMatch
```

(which you would have to make your own keybinding for).  Just trigger that command to skip the next possible match - so follow this order:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on the first `order`
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to enable whole word matching
3. trigger the command `Add Selection To Previous Find Match`
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to select the next `order`

It sounds like a bit of a hassle but they are common commands to know - to skip the next match and to toggle Whole Word matching.

[That little box that opens with the Find options is a little glitchey in that it seems to sometimes also enable the case sensitivity option as well - which isn't a problem in your example.]

[image: toggle whole word find next match demo]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark, really appreciate it! Apologies, I should have specified this more clearly in my initial question, but is it possible to also avoid selecting the text "order" that is contained within the string on line 3 -- i.e to just get the actual variable `order` on lines 1 and 3?

Comment: Yes, but you will have to incorporate another command - to skip the next find match - into your steps.  I edited the answer to show that command.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for adding that -- appreciate the help!

Comment: I had to downvote this answer since ctrl+d simply jumps to the next word matched by the find and replace. What I (and the poster) are really searching for is a more intelligent next word match using something like the `Go to next Symbol Highlight` but also having it actually highlight the word.

Comment: @tnrich Do you want to select ALL occurrences of current symbol or just the next (the OP says "I just want to select the actual variable order on lines 1 and 3" but the title says next...)?